# How do I deal with old resource files remaining in an updated install for android or ios?

Tags: android, ios, embedded-resource, updates

I deploy apps for Android and iOS, and I need to start updating these apps with new images.  I've had complaints from users about old images showing in updated apps, and when I update with new images under different names I get the occasional complaint that the app keeps getting bigger and hogging storage.  I remove old / unused images from the project before sending an update, but apparently these old images are sticking around on the users' devices.
  I need a best practice for getting rid of these old resources in iOS and Android.

Comment: I had a similar problem when replacing a nib-based controller by a pure code-based. The nib file was still present in the app bundle, causing strange errors. Fortunately this happened while testing, before the app went to the store. - I have no idea how to solve this. Did you try to ask at the Apple Developer forums or at Apple Technical support?

Answer (score 0):

On iOS the old resources are automatically cleared when you build for production (not true for debug, which requires you to clean and then build).

Comment: My concern is not the project itself.  It's the user's install.  When an app installs on a particular device, it unpacks its ancillary files into private storage. When an app is updated, the update will not overwrite an existing "Img1.png" resource with the one from the update, so the old image still appears after the update even if the developer has replaced that image in the project.  Ergo, I use 'Img2', 'Img3', etc. when I update - so the app uses the new img.  But I need to also ensure that the old imgs (no longer included or referenced in the project) are removed from the user's device.

Comment: I have never once come across this on iOS. I have done updates for apps that change images with the same file name and it works just fine...